# jQuery: change element position depending on screen width

Tags: jquery, html, css

How can I change the element position in real-time when I resize the screen?

For example, if screen is initially > 500px the element should be in x position, else if I resize the screen and make it smaller, the element should be repositioned. This must be made without pressing a button.

jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/zjgrmf24/2/

HTML:

```
<body>
 <div class="change_offset">
   reposition
 </div>
 <div class="here">
   move here
 </div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
.here {
  margin-top:200px;
  margin-left:100px;
}
.change_position {
  position: absolute;
}
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  herePos = $('.here').offset();
  change = $('change_offset');

  if($('body').width() < 500)
  {
    change.css({
        left: herePos.left + "px",
      top: herePos.top + "px"
    })
  }
  else
  {
    change.css({
        left: 'auto',
      top: 'auto'
    })
  }
})
```

Comment: Is the `.here` element always in the same place? If so you can achieve this in CSS alone without needing any JS code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `resize` event:

```
function handleResize() {
  herePos = $('.here').offset();
  change = $('change_offset');

  if($('body').width() < 500)
  {
    change.css({
        left: herePos.left + "px",
      top: herePos.top + "px"
    })
  }
  else
  {
    change.css({
        left: 'auto',
      top: 'auto'
    })
  }
}
$(document).ready(handleResize);
$(window).on("resize", handleResize);
```

---

Note: Your code is falling prey to [*The Horror of Implicit Globals*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html). Declare your variables.

Comment: Ah, sorry about the variables, I'm using CoffeeScript :)

Answer (score 0):

See here https://jsfiddle.net/zjgrmf24/5/

First thing I recognized, is that you didn't use the correct selectors.
Additional you should make use of window resize too.

```
var resize = function() {
  herePos = $('.here').offset();
  change = $('.change_position');

  if($('body').width() < 500)
  {
    change.css({
        left: herePos.left + "px",
      top: herePos.top + "px"
    })
  }
  else
  {
    change.css({
        left: 'auto',
      top: 'auto'
    })
  }
}

$(document).ready(resize);
$(window).on('resize', resize);
```